# Substituting entire IndexedBase objects in Sympy

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I have an expression for the entropy `h` written in terms of the discrete distribution `p`, which is an IndexedBase.

```py
import sympy as sym

x = sym.Idx("x")
p = sym.IndexedBase("p")
N_X = sym.Symbol("N_X", positive=True)

h = -sym.summation(p[x] * sym.log(p[x]), (x, 1, N_X))
```

Pretty printing `h` outputs:

[image]

I want to replace `p` by an expression in terms of the joint distribution `q`. Mathematically, I want to replace p by

[image]

Here is my attempt:

```py
y = sym.Idx("y")
N_Y = sym.Symbol("N_Y, positive=True")
q = sym.IndexedBase("q")
h.subs(p, sym.summation(q[x,y], (y, 1, N_Y)))
```

This raises a type error:

```py
TypeError: 
The base can only be replaced with a string, Symbol, IndexedBase or an
object with a method for getting items (i.e. an object with a
`__getitem__` method).
```

I get that the sum is not an `IndexedBase`, and that is an issue. But I do not know how to solve this: is there a way to create an `IndexedBase` that is represented in this way (as a sum of an `IndexedBase` `q`)?

Comment: You can use `h.xreplace({p[x]: sym.summation(q[x,y], (y, 1, N_Y))})`

Comment: @OscarBenjamin Thank you, that works. Could you maybe add a short description of why this works as `subs` does not? (Also, you can add this as an answer - I'll accept it.)